# FCM push notification not received by device when app is closed in background - Flutter Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) . My problem is: FCM push notification is not received by the device when the app is closed in recent tabs.
It works fine when the app is in foreground or in background. But, When I closed it from background , I didn't receive any notification in the notification tray.

I saw many post and tried many solutions, but nothing works in my case :(

Steps I've tried :

1. I've added fcm in dependencies & applied google plugin in my build.gradle
   here's my `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.myapplication.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
}
```

2.I've added google-services dependecy in my project/build.gradle
Here's my `project/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

3. setting android:enabled="true" & android:exported="true" in manifest.xml
   Here's my `app/src/main/Manifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:label="partner_location_project"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
   ....
   ....
   ....
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Here's my dart file where i've declared FCM.

```
class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  void fcm_listener() async {
    try {
      var token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("fcm token = $token");
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch $message");
        },
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume $message");
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("fcm exception");
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fcm_listener();
  }
```

I am testing it on real device(realme 6 pro).
(I am using firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0)
Any ideas are appreciated!!

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm currently facing the exact same problem, but only on a realme device. On other test devices the push is received. Maybe it's some battery optimizations from realme?

Comment: @BenjaminMenrad I don't know how it solved. It's solved automatically after some clean, rebuild & restart

Answer (score 1):

Check this working example: **[Flutter_Firebase_Notification](https://github.com/pratikbutani/Flutter_Firebase_Notification)**

**Sample Code:**

```
Future<void> myBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  return MyAppState()._showNotification(message);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/pratikbutani/Flutter_Firebase_Notification/blob/master/lib/main.dart)